# Qualcomm's Vuforia without Unity

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm new to Vuforia's SDK.
after i have compiled and ran the sample app.
i tried to create my own 3D object in order to do that Qualcomm want you to download Unity's Game engine.
they have an extension for it for eclipse.

my question is. is there a way to build 3D model without buying the 400$ or the 1500$ pro unity?
I saw some stuff about openGL but didn't really understand if i can replace Unity.

the  online target manger let's you create two targets:
1.SDK (Eclipse, Ant, Xcode, etc.)
2.Unity Editor

but what about generating 3D models?

Comment: Unity is awesome and free. The learning curve is pretty small as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuforia is "free" if you already have unity. Otherwise, you're stuck with no rendering engine and having to pay 400-1500.

I would suggest using the Metaio SDK. It's free (just with a small watermark in the bottom left hand corner), and includes a 3d rendering engine with the SDK.

It also supports all types of 3D models including FBX, MD2 and OBJ.  So you can use http://www.blender.org/ to create 3d models with it.

Metaio also offers the following webinars/tutorials that should be relevant for you:

- Webinars about using the Metaio SDK with Android, iOS, and Unity: https://dev.metaio.com/webinars/
- Webinar about AR content creation in Blender: https://dev.metaio.com/helpdesk/webinars/content-creation-and-management/
- Step by step tutorials and sample codes: http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/getting-started/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unity 3D is now being offered for Free if you are using it for non-commercial projects. They charge a licensing fee if you wish to use it commercially.